# HQL uses 'only' the property of first child in the where clause

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, orm, hql

I am using @Inheritance ( strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)

The parent class is an abstract class and has two children. Device and System

```
  public abstract class Parent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idParent")
    protected int parentId;

    abstract public String getManufacturer();

    abstract public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer);

    abstract public Date getUpdated();

    abstract public void setUpdated(Date updated);
    }

    public class Device extends Parent {

    @Column(name = "Device_Manufacturer")
    private String manufacturer;

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return this.manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String Manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    @Column(name = "Device_Last_Edit")
    private Date updated;

    public Date getUpdated() {
        return this.updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(Date updated) {
        this.updated = updated;

    }
    }

    public class System extends Parent {

    @Column(name = "System_Manufacturer")
    private String manufacturer;

    public Date getUpdated() {
        return this.updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(Date updated) {
        this.updated = updated;

    }

    @Column(name = "System_Last_Edit")
    private Date updated;

    public Date getUpdated() {
            return this.updated;
        }

        public void setUpdated(Date updated) {
            this.updated = updated;

        }

    }
```

When I query with where clause

> Parent.manufacturer = 'ABC'

, the query generated by HQL queries both children by doing a union of System and Device.

But it applies the where clause to

> Device_Manufacturer

only and not on

> System.Manufacturer

I tried using

> Type(Parent) = System

in the where clause but still HQL generates same SQL

Comment: Post full code of `Device` your current implementation lack of `getManufacturer()` method (and some other).

Comment: I will post it asap. But just fyi, my implementation has all the getters and setters. So I have **getManufacturer(){return this.manufacturer}** and **setManufacturer(String Manufacturer){this.manufacturer = manufacturer}**